# Is there a way to create keyboard macros through an android app?

Tags: java, android, driver

First of all, I am extremely new to coding and I just learned the basics of java. I want to do an android app as my first project. The idea of the app would be to have buttons on your phone which would work as keyboard macros. I was wondering if I also needed to create specific windows drivers for it or if I could just make it run on the default windows keyboard drivers? As I said I am super new to all of this (about 10hrs of programming experience), so feel free to correct me and educate me as much as you want! I won't take it personally, I'm looking to learn :)

Comment: Are you wanting to make the macros on an Android device or on a Windows device? What functions will the macros have (e.g. replace keywords with expanded text, perform a specific action on the device)?

Comment: @WebSpence It would be macros for Windows. It's for a game where you need 2 keys, and I want to use the app to activate the 2 keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set up some sort of communication between the app and your PC. You wouldn't need to do anything with the keyboard drivers. Java has something called the "Robot class" which allows you to simulate a keypress.

Here is the documentation on the robot class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

As for the communications, you will need to create a server/client connection. One of your devices will act as the client (probably your phone) and one will act as the server (probably your PC).

This is just a rough idea of how it would work but:

When you tap the button on your phone, it would send some specified data to your server that is running on your PC. You should set the data that gets sent from the client to the server as the key(s) keycode that you would like it to simulate so it will be easier to implement. When the server gets data from the client, it should send that data to the robot.keypress(data) function.

This honestly sounds like it will be a big project for your skill level but I wish you the best of luck on this. This will probably be a frustrating experience but don't let it get the better of you.